# Nvidia Dual monitor settings reset on boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I know this has been asked a thousand times, but none of the solutions here have worked for me.

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04. I have an nvidia GeForce GT 630 card, using 2 identical monitors - one on the VGA port, one on the DVI.

Every time I reboot I have to switch the side that the monitor is set up on. I've tried:

- running `sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-settings` as root and savings the settings to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
- copying the produced xorg.conf file to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf`

Anyone got any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup your displays using `nvidia-settings`, then start `xfce4-display-settings` and verify your settings. After closing that dialog and logging out and in, the config should be permanent.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. I seem to have lost transparency somewhere along the way, but I can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: Did work in Linux Mint Cinnamon, too. There it is called Display in the start menu.

Comment: It doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04. The settings don't persist.

Comment: On stock Ubuntu 20.04 this same idea did the trick: turn on the second monitor in nvidia-settings and then right click on desktop and open Display Settings from that context menu. Fiddle a bit with the settings, hit apply, reboot, and two monitors were finally enabled.

Comment: Also worked on ElementaryOS 5.1.7 by going to the Displays settings. Thank you!